# Determine if a view is inside a UIPopOverController

Tags: iphone, ipad, class, uipopovercontroller

I have a class, and I use it for both for iPhones and iPads.  When I use it with an iPad, I put it in a `UIPopOverController`.  I want to change the buttons in the `UINavigationController` based on whether it is in a `UIPopOver` or not.  How can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the macro/function (not sure exactly what the term for it is) `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` to check which kind of device you are currently running on.  Currently the two values this can return is `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` and `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    //do stuff
}
```